# Highcharts tooltip not showing on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, safari, highcharts

I have a scatter chart with 3 series, one for points on the x axis, one for points on the y axis, and one for everything else. Tooltips are enabled and I have a formatter that creates the tooltip text for the various series. Everything is working when using firefox, the tooltips look as expected. But with chrome or safari, the tooltips do not appear for points on the x axis. Points from the other series work as expected.

I have stopped in the formatter function and all seems nominal but the tooltip does not display. Any ideas what is going on here or possible workarounds?

Comment: Recreate issue on jsFiddle, please.

Comment: I had a problem with ver 2.8.8, but was solved upgrading to last version

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your tooltip:

```
useHTML: true
```